# How can I output this JSON file as a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, json, html, html-table

I have a JSON file which I would like to output as a HTML table using pure Javascript. What should the JS code look like? The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
"FIELD1":"A ",
"FIELD2":" B ",
"FIELD3":" C ",
"FIELD4":" D"
},
{
"FIELD1":"E ",
"FIELD2":" F ",
"FIELD3":" G ",
"FIELD4":" H"
},
{
"FIELD1":"I ",
"FIELD2":" J ",
"FIELD3":" K ",
"FIELD4":" L"
  }
]
```

Here is a jsbin for your convenience:

http://jsbin.com/nulol/1/edit

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: First you start out with a for loop..

Comment: Ok, a for loop, wait I think I have one here somewhere

Comment: no, that's a hoola hoop. that's for going in horizontal circles. you need a for loop, which goes in vertical circles

Comment: Sure, I am a beginner : D Anyways, I found a loop and put it in the JS file (http://jsbin.com/nulol/1/edit) and I also put a window.addEventListener in that file to start it off.

Comment: Here's a nice example of using the Handlebars templating libary: http://jsfiddle.net/gazraa/xfWKF/ It might be overkill for smaller projects, but it's a nice way to render HTML tables from json.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for that:

```
    var data = [
  {
    "FIELD1":"A ",
    "FIELD2":" B ",
    "FIELD3":" C ",
    "FIELD4":" D"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1":"E ",
    "FIELD2":" F ",
    "FIELD3":" G ",
    "FIELD4":" H"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1":"I ",
    "FIELD2":" J ",
    "FIELD3":" K ",
    "FIELD4":" L"
  }
]

document.getElementById('codeTarget').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

or you could use jQuery to target the element and then use its .html() method:

```
var JSONoutput = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
$('pre#codeTarget').html(JSONoutput);
```

Just be sure to put it in a pre tag so it will format nicely.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/disule/33pqS/1/).

Comment: The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON. In your example, the output is not a HTML table. Could you please exemplify so that the result actually is a HTML table? It would make it easier to understand and reverse engineer your code.

Comment: Ah, you want the data to be tabular when output. In that case, you should use a templating system like [Handlebars]http://handlebarsjs.com/). It's pretty straightforward. Here's an article to get you started, and it even puts data into a table: [dhtmlexamples.com/2011/04/15/getting-started-with-handlebars-js-templating-language-in-javascript/](http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/04/15/getting-started-with-handlebars-js-templating-language-in-javascript/)